# Here is my source code of a page. I need to click on a "Click Here" element Any suggestions how to do this using selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium

Below is a sample of the source code of a page. I need to click on the "Click Here" element, any suggestions how to do this using `Selenium Webdriver`?

```
<div class="railcontent">
    <a href="https://qafltgefleet.comfin.ge.com/MyFleetOfficeAppNoticeDisplayManager.jsp?propFile=FEEDBACK.properties" target="_blank">Click Here</a>
</div>
```

Comment: link doesn't work! You can paste the HTML into a Code Block (the button that shows `{ }` when you edit your post)

Comment: What's wrong with this? What doesn't work?

Comment: Well if you keep asking questions like this one, you are going to be banned from StackOverflow pretty soon. You really should read [How To Ask help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and the comments you've gotten on [your last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24057807/selenium-click-button)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that is NOT the rendered object, but in the event that it is, you can click it by using this CSS selector:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.railcontent > a[href*='NoticeDisplayManager']")).click();
```

Comment: Hi sircapsalot, sry above code is not workout...please suggest if any anther way...

Comment: it could be a number of things.. are you sure you've opened your page using `driver.open("http://url")`?

Comment: see below i opened page like this

Comment: see below i opened page like this BrowserAction.openBrowser(url)